# Fixtures load for inner class model / Play framework

Tags: playframework, yaml

I have a model in an inner class (because there will be many lists and I don't want to have a separate Java file for each of them):

```
package models;

public class Lists {

    @Entity
    public class City extends Model {
        String name;
    }   
}
```

Now I tried to load yaml fixtures as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598590/bind-to-an-inner-class-in-snakeyaml-play-framework):

```
Lists$City(Berlin):
  name: Berlin
```

The result is that a raw is created, but the name column is empty. When City is not an inner class, everything works fine. What can be wrong? I'm using Play Framework 1.2.5